# Using TSQL to perform calculations

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Ive got a table called NewCodes with the following records

```
| NewCode  | Mapping              |
| -------- | --------------       |
| pp1      | [US1] + [US5]        |
| qq1      | [US8] – [US9]        |
| ww1      | [RE5] + RE6] + [RE7] |
| zx1      | [KJ1] – [XC4]        |
```

Ive got another table called Source Codes which contains a list of values assigned to all the code in the mapping column.

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| US1 | 35 |
| US5 | 10 |
| US8 | 20 |
| US9 | 5 |
| RE5 | 7 |
| RE6 | 8 |
| RE7 | 6 |

I am trying to figure out a way of assigning a value to the codes in the NewCode column using the calculations  defined in the Mapping column. I currently use SSMS. So for example.

I have no idea how to attempt this and I was wondering anyone could help

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this in SQL. I'd first fire the person who designed your first table for a really badly thought out design, and then hire someone new to redesign it entirely so that it's actually usable.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the production doesn't get too much more complicated than the example then this can be done.  Specifically:

- Only addition and subtraction can be performed, or at least there is no concern for order of operations.
- The expressions are all well and consistently formed.
- All variables exist in *SourceCodes*.  (This could be overcome using a LEFT JOIN and providing a default value like 0).
- The level of the SQL Server supports *string_split*.  (Though I used to split with xml back in the day so this can be overcome.)

The following query will do the following.

- Split each Mapping into a table of symbols.
- Determine the proper order of symbols since *string_split* is non-deterministic.
- Normalize the symbols so the codes in brackets will match what is found in *SourceCodes*.
- Accumulate the result for each new code.
- Return the accumulated result in the last row for each new code partition.

The secret sauce in this solution is the use of recursive CTEs to act like for loops.  The first instance is used when determining the order of symbols.  In order to determine the start index for successive occurrences of the same symbol the unioned part of the CTE gets the char index from the previous.  The second instance in a similar fashion to accumulate values except it relies on the convention that an operator appears on every even row and code on every odd one.

```
WITH Symbols AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NewCode, Symbol ORDER BY Symbol) [SymbolSeqNum]
    FROM NewCodes
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT value [Symbol]
        FROM string_split( Mapping, ' ')
    ) x
)
, UnnormalizedOrderedSymbols AS (
    -- since string_split is nondeterministic we need a way to restore the order.
    SELECT NewCode, Symbol, SymbolSeqNum, CHARINDEX(Symbol, Mapping, 1) SymbolOrderIndex
    FROM Symbols
    WHERE SymbolSeqNum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.NewCode, s.Symbol, s.SymbolSeqNum, CHARINDEX(s.Symbol, s.Mapping, os.SymbolOrderIndex + 1) SymbolOrderIndex
    FROM UnnormalizedOrderedSymbols os 
    INNER JOIN Symbols s ON s.NewCode = os.NewCode AND s.Symbol = os.Symbol AND s.SymbolSeqNum = os.SymbolSeqNum + 1
)
, NormalizedOrderedSymbols AS (
    SELECT NewCode
        , CASE SymbolType WHEN 'Code' THEN SUBSTRING(Symbol, 2, LEN(Symbol) - 2) ELSE Symbol END [Symbol]
        , SymbolType
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NewCode ORDER BY SymbolOrderIndex) [SymbolOrderIndex]
    FROM UnnormalizedOrderedSymbols
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT CASE WHEN Symbol LIKE '[[]%]' THEN 'Code' ELSE 'Operator' END [SymbolType]
    ) x
)
, RunningTotal AS (
    SELECT NewCode, c.Value, SymbolOrderIndex
    FROM NormalizedOrderedSymbols o
    INNER JOIN SourceCodes c ON c.Code = o.Symbol
    WHERE o.SymbolOrderIndex = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rt.NewCode
        , CASE op.Symbol
            WHEN '+' THEN rt.Value + c.Value
            WHEN '-' THEN rt.Value - c.Value
        END
        , num.SymbolOrderIndex
    FROM RunningTotal rt 
    INNER JOIN NormalizedOrderedSymbols op ON op.NewCode = rt.NewCode AND op.SymbolOrderIndex = rt.SymbolOrderIndex + 1
    INNER JOIN NormalizedOrderedSymbols num ON num.NewCode = rt.NewCode AND num.SymbolOrderIndex = rt.SymbolOrderIndex + 2
    INNER JOIN SourceCodes c ON c.Code = num.Symbol
)
SELECT x.NewCode, x.Value
FROM (
    SELECT rt.NewCode, rt.Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rt.NewCode ORDER BY SymbolOrderIndex DESC) rn
    FROM RunningTotal rt
) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
ORDER BY NewCode
```

This is obviously is not a very good use of SQL Server and you're probably better off writing a script to perform whatever you're trying to accomplish.